# How to get information from a table which related to an aggregate function from other table

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, aggregate-functions

I have two tables comments and users
The comments table has comments for matches (match_static_id, comment, timestamp, user_id)
I get the max(timestamp) group by the match_id my problem is who can I get the username of the max(timestamp) from users table (id, username)

```
SELECT 
    MAX( comments.timestamp ) AS maxtimestamp,
    users.username
FROM  `comments`
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = comments.user_id 
GROUP BY match_static_id
```

This last query giving me a wrong username (not the user who makes the last comment of a match)
How can I get the username of the max(timestamp)
NOTE:I want a way without a subquery if it is possible because I have a huge database tables and the optimized queries are a priority for me

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM comments c
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM comments GROUP BY match_static_id) as l 
    ON l.timestamp = c.timestamp
INNER JOIN users
    ON users.id = comments.user_id
```

Comment: I edit ur answer and after edit i found that this answer is just giving the user of the last comment and I want (the user of the last comment of a match)

Comment: OK i have modified the query you can test

Comment: sorry this is not working it gives the same result for all records i do not think this is right

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you want. I have changed the position of group by try once more.